# Constraint on static

Tags: java, jvm

`static` methods can call only static methods/fields from same class. Questions:

1. Why non static methods/fields shall not be made available to `static` because once `static`  method has been called then JVM has created an object for it, which can access other parts of class if JVM allows?
2. Why does `static` methods allow objects from non static methods of other classes. Imposing restriction that they can access only `static` of other classes and letting a `static` access non static members of same class will cause any difference?

Comment: I hope this bulk of downvotes comes with some good suggestion.

Comment: `once Static method has been called than JVM has created an object for it` No JVM does not create an object.

Comment: you cannot access anything unless you have an object for it. You just don't have access to it.

Comment: @Blakbird You can access a static member of a class without creating an object.

Comment: And how you think JVM makes it available to you ? How does it associate it to some class ? I hope you got my question !

Answer (score 3):

Following is the java language specification for the static methods and fields. Hope it will help you

**8.3.1.1. static Fields**

If a field is declared static, there exists exactly one incarnation of the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class may eventually be created. A static field, sometimes called a class variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized (§12.4).

A field that is not declared static (sometimes called a non-static field) is called an instance variable. Whenever a new instance of a class is created (§12.5), a new variable associated with that instance is created for every instance variable declared in that class or any of its superclasses.

**8.4.3.2. static Methods**

A method that is declared static is called a class method.

It is a compile-time error to use the name of a type parameter of any surrounding declaration in the header or body of a class method.

A class method is always invoked without reference to a particular object. It is a compile-time error to attempt to reference the current object using the keyword this (§15.8.3) or the keyword super (§15.11.2).

A method that is not declared static is called an instance method, and sometimes called a non-static method.

An instance method is always invoked with respect to an object, which becomes the current object to which the keywords this and super refer during execution of the method body.

Comment: My question is why these rules have been formulated this way, if there is change that I have assumed is made, will it make Java less beautiful.

Comment: I think Blackbird knows this... He is asking "why?"

Comment: Well there is no central repository for WHY a particular style has been chosen . But you can go through the JSRs and from there you may get some hints.

Answer (score 3):

A non-static method has an implicit `this` object to can call on other non-static methods

A static method cannot implicitly call a non-static method as it has no object to implicitly use.  There is nothing to stop you explicitly using an object to call a method.

e.g.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        new Main().nonstatic(); // calls non-static method
    }

    public void nonstatic() {
        nonstatic2(); // calls non-static object with implicit reference to "this"
    }

    public void nonstatic2() {
        staticMethod(this);
    }

    public static void staticMethod(Main main) {
        main.nonstatic3(); // static calls non-static with explicit object.
    }

    public void nonstatic3() {
    }
```

> static methods can call only static methods/fields from same class.

This is not true as the example shows.

> Why non static methods/fields shall not be made available to static because once static method has been called then JVM has created an object for it,

The JVM could create an object automagically, but this is unlikely to be useful, esp if the object has no default constructor.

> which can access other parts of class if JVM allows?

It could allow, but shouldn't IMHO as this would be more confusing than useful.

> Why does static methods allow objects from non static methods of other classes.

static methods allow objects from all classes, not just other ones.

> Imposing restriction that they can access only static of other classes and letting a static access non static members of same class will cause any difference?

The difference is you don't have an implicit instance of the class  This is the whole point of a static method.

If you wanted an implicit instance, you would use a non-static method.

Comment: Having object created is synonymous to creating object of other class and access it. Its helpful but still not clearing my doubt.

Comment: @Blackbird I have answered each point in turn.  It is not clear to me where the confusion comes from.  static vs non-static is perhaps much simpler than you imagine.

Answer (score 2):

> once Static method has been called than JVM has created an object for
>   it

This is not true. Static methods can be called without creating an object of that class defining static method (*remember `public static void main()`*).

> Why does Static methods() allow objects from nonstatic methods of
>   other classes.

This is because `other classe` instance can exist irrespective of whether object of class defining static method (which access the the `other class`) exists.

Checkout [this link](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2001-11/03-qa-1121-mrhappy.html) for further insights.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand why `static` methods cannot call `non static`  methods or access `non static` variables you need to understand the diffeerence between a **class** and an **object**.

Java is an object oriented language. First you define a **class** which holds the state(instance variables) and methods which change the state(instance variables). 
But class is not an **object**. It is just a **template** for object creation, for which you use the `new` keyword (creating an instance of class). 
 Once you create an object its variables are in an inital state, and then you call methods which read or change object's state. Such variables and methods are `non static` in the sense that they require an object instance of a class.

However, in a class you can define a method that does not read or change the state. Method's behavior is not dependent at all on instance variables.
Such method can be declared static, which means no instance of the class is required to run the method.

You call a static method directly on a class ( without a reference to an object ):

```
MyClass.staticMethod();//will not read or change any state, because there is no object here
```

You can also call a static method on an object but will not access object's state, because its behavior does not depend nor does not change object's state. Call to `obj.staticMethod();` is the same as `MyClass.staticMethod();`:

```
//Create an instance of a MyClass
MyClass obj = new MyClass();

//will not read or change any state of obj. 
obj.staticMethod();
```

Note however that static methods are not completely stateless, they can still read or change the state of static varibables.

Note also that in Java you cannot override static methods(unlike in Delphi) - don't declare a method as static if you think subclasses will need to override it. 
Therefore as **rule-of-thumb** declare static methods in special purpose utility classes which don't need an instance anyway, like for example  [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), otherwise 
don't declare a method as static even if it doesn't read or change object's state because you might need to override it later.

Answer (score 1):

Why non static methods/fields shall not be made available to static because once static method has been called then JVM has created an object for it, which can access other parts of class if JVM allows?

If static methods were allowed to access non-static methods, that would mean, an instance level method would be called without an instance of the class. Then how will you override the method?. Overriding looks at the object to call/invoke the method and if you directly call non-static (instance) methods from static methods, which object is being used to call?.

And from a design perspective -

Assume you have a class called Dog.
Every dog eats, sleeps etc . But the most important thing to remember is all these things are specific to the Dog instance. and state of each object should be accessed via instance level methods - thats the whole point of encapsulation. If you say Dog.sleep(). Which dog should sleep?

Comment: This sounds reasonable,I am trying to make a program based on this, I will come again to you.